# woocommerce_add_order_item_meta hook sending only one argument; three expected

Tags: woocommerce, wordpress

I am using WC v. 2.3.9.

woocommerce_add_order_item_meta gets fired but my callback function only gets one parameter, three expected.

I want to add order item meta at the creation of the order.

Is this hook really available? Some rumour say that it's deprecated.

***Edit : after a few research it's the function woocommerce_add_order_item_meta() that is deprecated.***

Anyway I can find it in woocommerce/includes/class-wc-checkout.php. And the "do_action()" on this hook seems straightforward:

```
// Store the line items to the new/resumed order
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
   $item_id = $order->add_product(
    $values['data'],
    $values['quantity'],
    array(
       'variation' => $values['variation'],
       'totals'    => array(
       'subtotal'     => $values['line_subtotal'],
       'subtotal_tax' => $values['line_subtotal_tax'],
       'total'        => $values['line_total'],
       'tax'          => $values['line_tax'],
       'tax_data'     => $values['line_tax_data'] // Since 2.2
    )
      )
);
   if ( ! $item_id ) {
      throw new Exception( sprintf( __( 'Error %d: Unable to create order. Please try again.', 'woocommerce' ), 402 ) );
   }
   // Allow plugins to add order item meta
   do_action( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', $item_id, $values, $cart_item_key );
}
```

my custom plugin code:

```
public function __construct(){
   add_action('woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', array($this, 'charlie_ajoute_un_order_item_meta'));
}

public function charlie_ajoute_un_order_item_meta($item_id, $values, $cart_item_key){
   if (isset($values['cred_meta']['cred_post_id'])){
      $annonce_id = $values['cred_meta']['cred_post_id'];
   }
   elseif(isset($values['annonce_concernee'])){
      $annonce_id = $values['annonce_concernee'];
   }
   else{
      $annonce_id = 'turlututu';
/* as $values as well as $$cart_item_key are not set, my order item meta is always "turlututu".*/
   }
   wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'annonce_concernee', $annonce_id, true );
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Charles

Comment: Good on you for solving it. Maybe add your answer separately so you can mark it as the answer and thus, the question as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shame on me!I had not found necessary to add the last two arguments of the add_action() function. So the default number of argument being one, only one was passed to my callback.

so the right code for the add_action() function is:

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', array($this, 'charlie_ajoute_un_order_item_meta'), 10, 3);
```

Hope it may help someone.

Charles